# Could not determine type for: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(PATRF_ID)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nhibernate, oracle10g

It is giving me the above error for the NHibernate. I'm using VS 2010,C#, Oracle 10g. I tried searching google, stackoverflow but no luck. Following files are giving me error.

The exception `Could not determine type for: .....PatRegisterReferral, ...., Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(PATRF_ID)`

NHibernate mapping for `PatRegisterReferral`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="...." assembly="...">
  <class name=".......PatRegisterReferral, ....." table="......">
    <id name="Id" column="PATRF_ID" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="sequence" >
       <param name="sequence">PATRF_SEQ</param>
      </generator>
    </id>    
   <timestamp name="ModifyDate" column="MODIFY_DATE" generated="always" />
   <property name="CreateDate" column="CREATE_DATE" update="false" />
   <property name="CreateBy" column="CREATE_BY" update="false" />
   <property name="ModifyBy" column="MODIFY_BY" update="false" />
   <property name="EffDate" column="EFF_DATE" />
   <property name="ExpDate" column="EXP_DATE" />
   <many-to-one name="PatReferralStatus" class="PatReferralStatus">
    <column name="PATRS_CODE"></column>
   </many-to-one>      
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The `PatRegisterReferral` class:

```
 public class PatRegisterReferral
 {

    private PatReferralStatus _patReferralStatus = null;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(this.GetType().FullName);
        sb.Append(EffDate);
        sb.Append(ExpDate);            
        if (PatReferralStatus.Id != null) sb.Append(PatReferralStatus.Id);            
        return sb.ToString().GetHashCode();
    }

    public virtual DateTime EffDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? ExpDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string CreateBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string ModifyBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }

    public virtual PatReferralStatus PatReferralStatus
    {
        get { return _patReferralStatus; }
        set { _patReferralStatus = value; }
    }
}
```

NHibernate mapping for `PatReferralStatus`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="...." assembly="....">
 <class name="...., ...." table="...." mutable="false" batch-size="10" lazy="false">
  <id name="Id" column="PATRS_CODE" unsaved-value="0">
   <generator class="assigned"></generator>
  </id>
  <timestamp name="ModifyDate" column="MODIFY_DATE" generated="always" />
  <property name="Descrip" column="DESCRIP" />
  <property name="DescripFr" column="DESCRIP_FR" />
  <property name="EffDate" column="EFF_DATE" />
  <property name="ExpDate" column="EXP_DATE" />
  <property name="CreateBy" column="CREATE_BY" />
  <property name="CreateDate" column="CREATE_DATE" />
  <property name="ModifyBy" column="MODIFY_BY" />
  <bag name ="PatRegisterReferrals" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
   <key column="PATRS_CODE"></key>
   <one-to-many class="PatRegisterReferral"></one-to-many>      
  </bag>    
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Class definition for `PatReferralStatus`

```
public class PatReferralStatus
{
    private IList<PatRegisterReferral> _patRegisterReferrals = null;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(this.GetType().FullName);
        sb.Append(Descrip);
        sb.Append(DescripFr);
        sb.Append(EffDate);
        sb.Append(ExpDate);
        return sb.ToString().GetHashCode();
    }

    public virtual string Descrip { get; set; }
    public virtual string DescripFr { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EffDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? ExpDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string CreateBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string ModifyBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<PatRegisterReferral> PatRegisterReferrals
    {
        get { return _patRegisterReferrals; }
        set { _patRegisterReferrals = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your Id property in the class?

Comment: Sorry.. Forgot to mention that there is base class which has the ID property defined. If you want I'll past the base class as well.

Comment: Any one has any idea....

Comment: It would be nice to see your table definitions. It could have something to do with the use of `sequence`. What kind of DB do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution after struggling for 2 days. The ID was defined in the base class. And the base class was using generics. I defined wrong type in the `<T>` for the derived class. Sorry people for taking your time. Silly me..

Comment: For others: The typical reason for this error is when you are trying to call Map() for the complex type